# What is the correct way to use Winsock recv function in a loop?

Tags: c++, winsock

I'm working on a httpPlatformHandler server app. My recv loop works but uses the Sleep function to make it work. Without the Sleep call, it doesn't always get the posted data. I tried changing the blocking mode but it ended up waiting forever. Here is the code I have:

```
// Make the socket blocking
SetBlockingMode(ListenSocket, TRUE);

while (true)
{
    // initialize per request variables
    ud.ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    ud.ReceivedData.clear();

    // Accept incoming connection
    ud.ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (ud.ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        GetLastError(iResult, L"accept");
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Make the socket non-blocking
    SetBlockingMode(ud.ClientSocket, FALSE);

    // Receive the data
    while (true)
    {
        Sleep(5);

        // receive data from the client
        ZeroMemory(szRecvBuffer, sizeof(szRecvBuffer));
        iResult = recv(ud.ClientSocket, szRecvBuffer, sizeof(szRecvBuffer) - 6, 0);
        iLastError = WSAGetLastError();

        // add received data to the string variable
        if (iResult > 0) {
            ud.ReceivedData.append(szRecvBuffer);
            continue;
        }

        // connection closed
        if (iResult == 0) {
            break;
        }

        // break out of loop if would block
        if (iLastError == WSAEWOULDBLOCK) {
            break;
        }
    }

    // process request
    ProcessRequest();

    // Shutdown client socket
    iResult = shutdown(ud.ClientSocket, SD_SEND);

    // Close client socket
    closesocket(ud.ClientSocket);
}
```

Comment: See my [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A65863+http+pseudo) on the topic of writing proper reading code for HTTP messages.

Comment: That being said, you don't need `ZeroMemory()` before `recv()`, and you should use `iResult` when appending the data to your buffer: `ud.ReceivedData.append(szRecvBuffer, iResult);`

Answer (score 0):

Well, your are very close to ideal approach now.

You have discovered that you need to 'wait unitl there some income data in the socket',
and choosed to use 'looping sleep' approach,  which can not make you satisfied.

What if we can '*wait unitl one of our in-bound sockets become readable, while waiting yield CPU to other thread*'?
That will be perfect!
And that is called '**asynchronous IO**'.

Take a look at [http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-book/01_intro.html](http://www.wangafu.net/%7Enickm/libevent-book/01_intro.html)

I recommand you use some high-level asio lib like libevent or boost::asio, rather then implment asio approach from 'select/epoll...'.

Answer (score 0):

2 options (without making it an async operation).

1. you can have recv just block and wait to complete -- in which case set blocking mode to true.
2. if you don't want recv to block and you want to set blocking mode to false, then you can call select - which will wait until data arrives.

for #2, the common pattern is:

- loop recv() until it returns WSAEWOULDBLOCK
- then call select waiting for more data
- repeat